# Run without debugging in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

When I run my app on my phone from eclipse, it always runs in debug. This has only recently started to happen. I guess I must have inadvertently changed a preference or something, but can't work out what. Does anyone know how I can switch it back so I can run without debugging?

Thanks in advance

TAO

Comment: Just my "me too" comment.

Answer (score 8):

I found someone else reporting the same error

http://osdir.com/ml/AndroidDevelopers/2009-08/msg00603.html

They resolved it with a phone restart.

The same worked for me.... how frustrating!!!!!!

At least its working now.

Massive thanks Aaron Digulla for our help.

TAO

Comment: Worked for me when this started happening on my Xoom.

Answer (score 0):

Check the VM options in the project's properties. There should be something like `-Xdebug=...`. Remove that.

I suggest to duplicate the entry and create a second one without the debug options. Also note that under `Common`, you can save the launch config somewhere (for example in your project), so this setup doesn't get lost.

Comment: I think you mean "launch configuration" for the application in your first sentence.  Not the properties associated with the project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Please can you tell me where to find these settings.

Thanks

TAO

Comment: Use "Run Configurations..." in the "Run" menu. The VM options are on the "Arguments" tab.

Comment: OK, Run configurations is where I've been loking, but I have no 'Arguments' tab and no VM options.  The tabs are 'Android','Target' and 'Common'.  I'm using Galileo.

TAO

Comment: Ah, you're on Android. Then see this article: http://source.android.com/using-eclipse Basically, there should be a button "Debug" and "Run" in the toolbar of eclipse The run button is a green arrow, the debug button is a little green bug. Just click on the run button instead of the debug button.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I should have mentioned in my original post that I was on Android. I know the difference between the debug and run buttons in eclipse. My problem is that the run button (green arrow) always starts debug when I want to run my app on my phone. This is only a problems when running on the phone... I can run without debug on an AVD. 

As I said in my original post, I used to be able to run my app on my phone no without debug... this has only recently become a problem.

Comment: I've recently tried a couple more things to investigate this... 

1. I've tried running other apps from eclipse on my phone and they all work fine, so the problem is specific to my app.
2. I've manually created a signed build and installed this on my phone. When I start it, it waits for the debugger to connect.

It must be an app build setting or something.

Any ideas

Comment: Check whether you use any of this API: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html especially waitForDebugger()

Answer (score 0):

Just ran across this issue.
Sometimes the Eclipse Android dev environment sets the application property  `android:debuggable="true"` in the AndroidManifest.xml file.  This will cause your app to run in debug mode regardless of if you press 'run' or 'debug' in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I know this contribution comes a little late, but here it goes. Be sure you do not have any `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger()` method invoked since your code. If so, just remove or comment it and rerun your application.